# all files changed from read & write to read only without my permission

Tags: permissions

I upgraded to ubuntu 21.10 and it changed my files to read only. Now I can't create new folders or copy and paste files. States that destination is read only and cannot copy or paste.

Comment: Which files/directories/locations are read-only?

Comment: please [edit] your question to include what you upgraded from to 21.10 and how that upgrade was achieved.

Comment: If you are in your home, you can go to /home/  and do a `sudo chown -R yourname:yourgroupe yourdirectory` if you mean it is anywhere else edit your question

Comment: I think your filesystem may be mounted read only, possibly because of an error. Try reviewing the output of `mount` and `sudo dmesg`

Comment: @francoisP **NO! Don't `chown` anything!!!**

Comment: that's why I specified `if .....` else edit ... and so on :)

Comment: @francoisP A `chown` would **never** be the right answer.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

Your disk is probably in read-only mode due to file system errors.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: +1 This method is safe, effective, and directly addresses the most likely cause of the behavior.